# Using map created in res folder

Tags: android

This is probably realy noobish question but, i am unable to solve it. I dont know what i am doing wrong or what should i do, i checked some tuts but i wasnt able to solve it. So i created new folder in res called menu and created new file there called xyz.xml. Now i want to call it in activity with following R.menu.item ... But when i just write R. it doesnt show menu as option. I can call any map which are default here like layout etc, but maps which i created i cant call them. What should i do to solve  this?

Comment: Did you save your new xml? This is a very common mistake in Eclipse.

Comment: Saved and builded. Is maybe possible because i am loading setContentView from R.layout.main? and then in method i have to load from R.menu.

Comment: Do you want to load a Map from XML or a Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the menu file you create is called xyz.xml, then in your code you should use it as:

```
R.menu.xyz
```

Also, are you referring to the correct R? There's one R class used for the Android framework resources (android.R) and then there's one specific R class for your projects resources. To ensure you're using the right one you can use the fully qualified namespace, e.g. yourprojectsnamespace.R.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html for more information about Android menus.